# How to update BASH and Ruby in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rubygems

I'm start to learning Rails in freeCodeCamp.org on youtube. So im trying to install devise in rubygems.org
and i already pasted gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.3' in my Gemfile
and then when using bundle install
i saw this

```
Resolving dependencies....
responders-3.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.4.0, which is incompatible with the
current version, ruby 2.3.3p222
```

so im trying to update my ruby by using rvm and following steps in wrvm.io
This's show up

```
BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.1.20(4)-release)
```

i dont know to update BASH version and ruby version as well.

Comment: You did not specify what Ruby and what bash you have installed. There are many implementations of both available for Windows.

Comment: i already install ruby 2.3.3, and i have git bash and bash on ubuntu

Comment: Which Ruby distribution did you install? There are several ones: ActiveState, Cygwin (that's the one I use), Truffle Ruby, Ruby on WSL, and so on. Further, you said that you are using two bash versions. Are you using for this GitBash or ubuntu bash (WSL)?

Comment: i'm using  Ruby on WSL and ubuntu bash

Comment: and using gitBash when i want to creat new rails folder

Answer (score 1):

To update, open a Bash on Ubuntu on Windows window, and enter the following commands,

To check your Ruby version before updating,
`ruby -v`

To update all of your local package repositories,
`sudo apt-get update`

To upgrade Bash,
`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash`

To upgrade Ruby, the following guide should help you with this,
https://everydayrails.com/2017/12/18/ruby-upgrade-guide-for-rails.html